# $\int_{0}^{10} \int_{0}^{10} \int_{0}^{10} (x+y+z)$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to understand the $\int_{0}^{10} \int_{0}^{10} \int_{0}^{10} (x+y+z) dx dydz$   It has been a while since I took calculus $3$ but I thought the answer should be $150$ however its not.

The answer should be $15000$

Can someone please explain how we are coming up with such a large number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\begin {align} \int_{0}^{10} \int_{0}^{10} \int_{0}^{10} (x+y+z) dx dydz &= \int_{0}^{10} \int_{0}^{10} \left.\left( \frac{x^2}2+xy+xz\right)\right|_{x=0}^{x=10} dx dydz
\\&=\int_{0}^{10} \int_{0}^{10}(50+10y+10z) dy dz
\\&=\int_0^{10}\left.\left(50y+5y^2+10yz\right)\right|_{y=0}^{y=10} dz
\\ &=\int_0^{10}(500+500+100z)dz
\\ &=15000\end {align}$$

Answer (score 11):

Note that the integral (by symmetry) is equal to three times the integral $$\int_A x dxdydz$$

Where $A$ is $[0,10]^3$. But you can write the integral as the iterated integral $$\int_0^{10} dz\int_0^{10} dy \int_0^{10} xdx $$

Thus the integral is equal to $$3\times 10\times 10\times 10^2/2$$ which is indeed $15000$.